# RequireJS using path in other file

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I have a site developed in cakephp, backbone and requirejs.

Into my config file I have mapped my javascript and if I called jquery into this file all works fine.
If i call jquery into another file give me error that function is indefined like that jquery isn't loaded.

This is my fole that works fine config.js:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/site.com/js/",

    paths: {
        // Aliases for libraries, so that we can change versions from here
        jquery: "libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min",
        handlebars: "libs/backbone/template/handlebars",
        lodash: "libs/backbone/template/lodash.min",
        backbone: "libs/backbone/backbone-1.0.0.min",
        less:"libs/less/less-1.4.0-beta.min",
        helper:"app/helper",
        jquery_cookie:"libs/jquery/plugin/jquery.cookie",
        text:"libs/require/text-2.0.7"
    },

    shim: {
        "lodash": { exports: '_' },
        "handlebars": { exports: 'Handlebars' },
        "jquery": { exports: '$' },
        "backbone": {
            //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
            //backbone.js
            deps: ["helper", "lodash", "jquery"],
            //Once loaded, use the global "Backbone" as the
            //module value.
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        "jquery_cookie": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
            //,exports:"$"
        },
        "less": {
            exports:"less"
        }
    }

    // This is appended to every module loading request, for cache invalidation purposes
    // comment it on production
    , urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});

require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $("body").empty();
});
```

Instead if I write this into config.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/site.com/js/",

    paths: {
        // Aliases for libraries, so that we can change versions from here
        jquery: "libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min",
        handlebars: "libs/backbone/template/handlebars",
        lodash: "libs/backbone/template/lodash.min",
        backbone: "libs/backbone/backbone-1.0.0.min",
        less:"libs/less/less-1.4.0-beta.min",
        helper:"app/helper",
        jquery_cookie:"libs/jquery/plugin/jquery.cookie",
        text:"libs/require/text-2.0.7"
    },

    shim: {
        "lodash": { exports: '_' },
        "handlebars": { exports: 'Handlebars' },
        "jquery": { exports: '$' },
        "backbone": {
            //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
            //backbone.js
            deps: ["helper", "lodash", "jquery"],
            //Once loaded, use the global "Backbone" as the
            //module value.
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        "jquery_cookie": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
            //,exports:"$"
        },
        "less": {
            exports:"less"
        }
    }

    // This is appended to every module loading request, for cache invalidation purposes
    // comment it on production
    , urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});
```

And move the call to jquery into the default.ctp retrieve me the error of function undefined because doesn't load the jQuery I think.

default.ctp

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $("body").empty();
});
```

Why I can't use jquery into deafult.ctp?
I have to map into all files? I don't think so, can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: is this still a problem? If yes, how did you overcome?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your config.js run after you try to use jquery.
Try to check with log when your config file is run.